# Selecting all columns and constant value from Oracle table

Tags: sql, oracle, select, dml

How can I select all columns and add a column with a constant value in Oracle?

With MS SQL Server, I can use:

```
Select *,5 From TableA;
```

I will get this:

```
column1      column2    5
xx           xx         5
xx           xx         5
```

Answer (score 14):

See this tutorial: [Select constant as a Column](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Oracle/0040__Query-Select/Selectconstantasacolumn.htm)

```
Select *,5 as "ConstColumn" From TableA;
```

Answer (score 11):

Try,

```
Select TableA.*, 5 as "ColumnAlias" From TableA
```

Comment: @CooperMAN - looks like your new here to SO, if you mark the answer you'll get a couple of points and soon will earn the privilege to be able to upvote and downvote HTH

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is really possible, because the * character is not a replacing content.
I get back this error: ORA-00923